# Missing } inserted. \end{proof}

Tags: proof-package

I get a bunch of errors telling me:

> line 417: Missing { inserted. \end{proof} 
> line 417: Missing } inserted. \end{proof} 
> line 426: Missing { inserted. \end{proof} 
> line 426: Missing } inserted. \end{proof} 
> line 439: Missing { inserted. \end{proof} 
> line 439: Missing } inserted. \end{proof}

Some of the sample source code are:

> Line 417

```
\begin{proof}
    \begin{equation*}
        f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{c-c}{h}=0
    \end{equation*}
\end{proof}
```

> Line 426

```
\begin{proof}
    pending
\end{proof}
```

> Line 439

```
\begin{proof} 
    \begin{align*}
        \frac{d}{dx}(cf)&=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{cf(x+h)-cf(x)}{h} \\[0.2cm]
        &= c\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\[0.2cm]
        &=c\frac{df}{dx}
    \end{align*} 
\end{proof}
```

I will put up my usepackages just in case:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{proof}

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: The definition of `proof` with which I'm familiar is from `amsthm`.  In that case, it is assumed that `\begin{proof}` will be followed by text, not by a display.  Making the assumption that the package you are using has the same restriction, you can get around it by inserting "phony" text, `$ $`.  After that, a display is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Never disregard error messages and always look for the first one, which in your case is

```
! Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined.

See the ntheorem package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

And the error is due to the fact that `ntheorem` and `amsthm` fight each other in redefining `\newtheorem`.

Remove `ntheorem`.

If you want a “break style” (which I dislike), you need to build it, because `amsthm` doesn't offer it out of the box. You can consult its documentation to find

```
\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {}
  {}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {}% Note that final punctuation is omitted.
  {\newline}
  {}
```

(empty arguments are generally substituted with the default (not the punctuation argument).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{proof}

\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {}
  {}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {}% Note that final punctuation is omitted.
  {\newline}
  {}
\theoremstyle{break}

\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Something neat here to state.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
    \begin{equation*}
        f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{c-c}{h}=0 \qedhere
    \end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

I left `\usepackage{proof}`, but I don't think you want it, because it is for “logic proofs” and it has nothing to do with the `proof` environment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys after a few trial and error experiments, the error is caused by a conflict between

> \usepackage{ntheorem}

and

> \usepackage{amsthm}

I originally included \usepackage{ntheorem} because I want a break after Theorem heading, which I failed to accomplish with AMSTHM's \newtheoremstyle.